# Private variable in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have two classes under QT, one to make a form, the other to send the collected data on the serial port. There is a button to submit and send the information on the serial port. The first class "myform" contains the file descriptor variable and the slot function for the submit button.

```
    class myform: public QWidget
    {
      Q_OBJECT
      private slots:
      void submitclicked(void);
    public:
        myform(QWidget *parent = 0);

        // some vars...  
        QPushButton *submit;
        int serialfd;
    };
```

The second class "serialcom" inherits the first class, since I want to implement the slot function in that "serialcom" class.

```
    class serialcom : public myform
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        int serialdev_init(void);
        serialcom(myform *parent=0);

    private:
        // some vars...
    };
```

The serialfd file descriptor is getting initialized in the constructor for serialcom through serialdev_init(). I have checked, it is initialized properly. The problem is that when the SLOT for submit button is called, serialfd has garbage value (I mean inside the submitclicked() slot ), not the initialized value.

Isn't it supposed to preserve the value, or am I wrong to assume that ? I am pretty new to this QT or even C++ business, so please mind my stupidities if any...

Here is the main function...

```
    int main(int argc,char **argv)
    {
        QApplication app(argc,argv);

        myform *trial = new myform;

        serialcom *serial = new serialcom(trial);


        trial->show();

        return app.exec();
   }
```

Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: Could you show how you are instantiating `serialcom`, initializing `serialfd` ? I doubt you have two different objects ( serialcom and another myform object alone) or else what you say doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I don't think you understand signals and slots.  Logically, should the serial port have a class relationship with a form?  You do not want `serialcom` to subclass the form.  You want something to tell the form that when you click the submit button, to send it via serial port.

Comment: @mahesh : I do have two different objects. I have instantiated them in main (edited the post)

Comment: @Keith : Well, you are correct in saying I dont understand signals and slots. I thought that is what I was doing through submitclicked() SLOT... I am notifying the myform through that submitclicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derived class construction involves base class sub-object construction first followed by derived class sub-object. So, derived class object has two sub-objects.

```
 myform *trial = new myform;
```

`trail` has a sub-objects of type `QWidget, myform`. Now this `myform` sub-object has it's own member variable(s) `serialfd` which is uninitialized. Now, `trial` cannot access `serialcom` members because a derived class can access base class members but the otherwise is not true.

```
 serialcom *serial = new serialcom(trial);
```

The same happens with this statement too except that `serial` has it's own sub-objects `QWidget, myform, serial`.

> The serialfd file descriptor is getting initialized in the constructor for serialcom through serialdev_init().

Now the two `myform` sub-objects has no relation. You are setting `serialfd` of this sub-object but seeing the `serialfd` of `trail` sub-object.

```
 trial->show();
```

Hope you understood what you are doing wrong.

Comment: You mean I should not create trial, just create serial object. I did that, but now the application hangs after clicking submit. Previously it was at least taking the input. Anyway, thanks for the input...appreciate it. Will post if I break it...

Comment: I don't know how `qt` internals work but that was what you were doing wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much Mahesh, that is the correct answer. Cant believe that slipped my mind. I've been stuck at this for 3 days...thanks a million. Oh, and the application does not hang, its just waiting on read from serial port, thats why it appeared hung :)  Thanks again.